# Unable to create JNDI API Context while using security policy

Tags: java, jndi

My current code works **without** setting security policy. However, when I add the line:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

I get the following error for my JMS application:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
    at backend.GameDetailsTopicPublisher.createJNDIContext(GameDetailsTopicPublisher.java:54)
    at backend.GameDetailsTopicPublisher.<init>(GameDetailsTopicPublisher.java:34)
    at backend.Server.receiveActiveGameUserQueue(Server.java:71)
    at backend.Server.main(Server.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:225)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals.getStaticHabitat(Globals.java:102)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.<init>(SerialInitContextFactory.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:682)
    ... 7 more
Program aborted
```

My security.policy file looks like:

```
grant {
 permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535", "connect,accept";
 permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:80", "connect";
 permission java.io.FilePermission "UserInfo.txt", "read,write";
 permission java.io.FilePermission "OnlineUser.txt", "read,write";
 permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
};
```

If I allow all permissions by making my security.policy file:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

everything works normally. So I Reckon the problem has something to do with security permissions?

I am using glassfish for the server. I have included **gf-client.jar**, **javaee.jar** and **appserv-rt.jar** from the glassfish5/glassfish/lib folder, in the build path of the project.

My initialization for the JNDI InitialContext looks like:

```
private InitialContext jndiContext;

private void createJNDIContext() throws NamingException {
    System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", host);
    System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    try {
        jndiContext = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not create JNDI API context: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I am new to the whole JMS world. Would appreciate any advice and help!
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the full stack-trace?

Comment: Do you have a `jndi.properties` on your classpath? If so, can you share its contents?

Comment: Hey Justin! I just added the full stack trace to the question. However, I am not sure what a jndi.proprties is, I have not added that.